# Auto Logout from Asp.net Identity when user is Inactive

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am devoloping Asp.net mvc application with Asp.net Identity framework with a requirement of user should be autologout after 10 mins only when the user is inactive(With out mouse movement/Click).I have tried with code which works as user logsout even when the user is active in the application,Can any one help me out in accomplishing these ASAP.Response would be appreciated

Please find my Starup.cs file code here:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Owin;
using ADFV2External.Models;
using ADFV2External;

namespace ADFV2ExternalLogin
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);


            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //   consumerKey: "",
            //   consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //   appId: "",
            //   appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            //{
            //    ClientId = "",
            //    ClientSecret = ""
            //});
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication
            (
            clientId: "f10e6987-f527-4eb2-a7d4-61a9d5175117",
            clientSecret: "qedLHH977-:ivxfAZNQ90:_"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to define activity as a server-side action like any request to server. By this approach, you can simply create a dictionary that contains last activity time for each user and you can create a task that selects dictionary elements with more that 10 mins difference with current time. So simply make them signed out.

Answer (score 0):

[ExpireTimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.expiretimespan%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) based on request/response mechanism. That means, that user will log out if there wouldn't be any HTTP request from user in 10 minutes from last response.

So I see 2 ways to solve your task:

1. You can initiate HTTP requests from page by mouse/keyboard events;
2. You can run timer (`setTimeout` function) on client side with its reset on mouse/keyboard events & send log out request when it stops. ExpireTimeSpan must be disabled.

But there may be trouble when user opens some pages.